# What if I reduce the amount of RAM allocated to Elastic Search for Azure Devops Server Express?

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, azure-devops

I just installed Azure Devops Server Express on my computer with 32GB of RAM (running Windows 10) and I noticed that Elastic Search that was installed as a part of Azure Devops setup now consumes 10GB of RAM.

This Azure Devops installation is for my personal use and will only see low usage.

I reduced the amount of RAM to 512MB initial/1GB max via Elastic Search manager utility.

However I am not sure what will be the outcome of this.

Does it mean the search will be slower (I am perfectly fine with this)?

Or does it mean that search functionality will just not work or will be "partially broken" (i.e. "in-memory index" will be incomplete or something like that)?

Comment: Where do you find the Elastic Search manager utility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For evaluation or personal use, you can use a basic configuration with as little as **2 GB** of RAM. Please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops-2020#single-server-deployment).

The size of RAM doesn't affect search results, but will cause performance issues like search speed and load time.